# Can I take the "Help" action to assist in saving throw against fear?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, fear, helping

If a party member is currently suffering from the frightened condition and gets a saving throw to end it at the end of their turn, can I use my Help action to give them advantage on the roll?

To put this in the context of role-playing, can my character grab them by the shoulders and help calm them down?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## RAW is NO

PHB, 192 for the HELP action states (emphasis mine):

> When you take the Help action, the creature you aid gains advantage on **the next ability check** it makes to perform the task you are helping with...
>
> Alternatively, you can aid a friendly creature **in attacking** a creature within 5 feet of you.

Saving throws are not Ability Checks or an Attack.

In addition, there are some character classes that do aid in such an activity. Namely, the Bard's Countercharm (PHB, 54)

> As an action, you can start a performance that...any friendly creatures within 30 feet of you have advantage on saving throws against being frightened or charmed.

Comment: Listen, you can *make* helping someone [an attack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvPugcb7QGE).

Comment: This answer would be improved if you mentioned the matter of how advantage is ruled by the DM.

Answer (score 4):

## No

The 'Help' action specifically says you can help with an ability check or an attack roll.  From the Basic Rules page 72:

> You can lend your aid to another creature in the
>   completion of a task. When you take the Help action,
>   the creature you aid gains advantage on the next **ability
>   check** it makes to perform the task you are helping with,
>   provided that it makes the check before the start of
>   your next turn.
>
> Alternatively, you can aid a friendly creature in
>   attacking a creature within 5 feet of you. You feint,
>   distract the target, or in some other way team up to
>   make your ally’s attack more effective. If your ally
>   attacks the target before your next turn, the first **attack
>   roll** is made with advantage.

A Saving Throw is neither an ability check nor is it an attack roll (a Saving Throw is its own thing), so the Help action doesn't apply.

Comment: Since advantage is by RAW often based on circumstantial bonuses, there is no reason not to try and make the suggestion that this ought to provide advantage ... the DM will rule one way or the other.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast while you are technically correct, since the DM can rule anything any way they want I feel like that doesn't add anything to the response.  If someone asks 'Does a rogue's sneak attack allow me to polymorph into a Tarrasque?' the correct answer is 'No', even though the DM could rule that it does.

Comment: Respectfully, no.  The matter of advantage is explicit regarding circumstance.  The polymorph into a Tarrasque isn't.  Why 'helping with a save' isn't a general rule is rather obvious, given the wide variety of spells that call for saves.  Some would lend themselves more to this circumstance than others.  This one looks to be a good fit.

Answer (score 3):

> A character can only provide help if the task is one that he or she
>   could attempt alone. (PHB 175)

As you normally cannot lift the *frightened* condition from someone else, you cannot help in it either.